# Showing a sequence convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $a_1,a_2>0$ and $a_{n+1}=\cfrac{2}{a_{n-1}+a_{n}}(n\ge2)$,

How to prove $a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: show that the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: @Nana, how to show that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

This is AMM(problem, E3388), maybe have other methods.

Comment: Isn't this solution a particular?